# How to pass result to HTML in Mojolicious?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I need to pass the result of
[`Mojo::mysql`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::mysql)
to `$variable` in HTML

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Mojolicious::Lite;
use Mojo::mysql;

helper mysql => sub {
    state $pg = Mojo::mysql->new( 'mysql://mysql://sri:s3cret@localhost/db' )
};

get '/index' => sub {
    my $c  = shift;
    my $db = $c->mysql->db;
    $db->query( 'select now() as time' )->hash;
};

app->start;

__DATA__

@@ index.html.ep
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title><%= title %></title></head>
<body><%= $db %></body>
</html>`
```

I need to pass the result of `$db` to index, but I don't know how to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never rendered your `index` template. To do so, call the `render` method on your controller. Any variables in your stash (or other arguments to the render function) are turned into variables in your template.

So we would have something like this:

```
get '/index' => sub {
    my $c  = shift;
    ...
    my $result = $db->query(...)->hash;
    return $c->render(template => 'index', result => $result);
};

...

__DATA__

@@ index.html.ep
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title><%= title %></title></head>
<body><%= dumper $result %></body>
</html>
```

(Here I've used the `dumper` helper so that the hash ref produces useful output, not just `HASH(0x123abc)`.)

Further reading:

- [Mojolicious::Guides::Rendering](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Guides::Rendering)
- [`render()` in Mojolicious::Controller](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Controller#render)

Comment: why only return a one line of db? when execute select * from tables;

Comment: @MemoR That seems to be a separate issue, unrelated to your question. If you look at the [Mojo::mysql::Results docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::mysql::Results), many ways to access the data in a result set are explained. The `->hash` method gets the next row of a result as a hash ref. You can use `->hashes` to get a collection of hash refs instead, or another method that suits your needs.